# I have created a Score class for pong, when I add my variable count += 1 it should continue to add but only stays at one

Tags: python, pong

here is my code :

```
import pygame
import ball
import paddle
from pygame.locals import*

class Score:

    def __init__(self, ball, paddle):
        self.numbers = [pygame.image.load('digit_0.bmp'),
                        pygame.image.load('digit_1.bmp'),
                        pygame.image.load('digit_2.bmp'),
                        pygame.image.load('digit_3.bmp'),
                        pygame.image.load('digit_4.bmp'),
                        pygame.image.load('digit_5.bmp'),
                        pygame.image.load('digit_6.bmp'),
                        pygame.image.load('digit_7.bmp'),
                        pygame.image.load('digit_8.bmp'),
                        pygame.image.load('digit_9.bmp'),
                        ]
        self.player = 0
        self.computer = 0
        self.secdig = 0
        self.ball = ball
        self.paddle = paddle
```

Cant figure out why points(paddle) only stays at one when the counter should continue to go up by 1 increments.

```
def points(self, paddle):
    count = 0
    point = 0
    if self.ball.x < paddle.getX():
        count += 1
        print(count)

def paint(self, surface):
    surface.blit(self.numbers[self.computer], (200, 30))
    surface.blit(self.numbers[self.secdig], (160, 30))
```

Comment: Because `count` is just an internal variable of `points` which is discarded when the function terminates. You want to modify an attribute of the object like `self.count` or something.

Comment: No problem. You should probably read the docs to get to grips with classes. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
self.count = 0
```

to your class and then use it inside **points function.**

```
def points(self, paddle):
    point = 0
    if self.ball.x < paddle.getX():
        self.count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make the count a class variable.

```
def __init__(self, ball, paddle):
    ...
    self.count = 0

def points(self, paddle):
    point = 0
    if self.ball.x < paddle.getX():
        self.count += 1
        print(count)
```

If you set `count` to 0 in the `points()` method, count is set to 0 again every time the method is called.